# Labels on check boxes not appearing correctly formatted on ipad and iphone

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that has check boxes in it which are not displayed correctly on IPad and Iphone. There is a large margin on either side of the check box.

HTML Code is:

```
    <dl class="dlcategories">
    <dt><font class="categories">Type:</font>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="condo" id="condo"><label>Condo</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="house" id="house"><label>House</label></dt></dl>
```

CSS code is:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;}

.dlcategories {
margin-top:10px;}

.categories{
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
color: #0E3544;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: 0px;
margin-top:10px;}
```

When displayed on browsers and android it looks good [(Screenshot)](http://s30.postimg.org/zdtcg00ap/image.png).

When displayed on iPad and iPhone, there is a larger left margin on the label [(Screenshot)](http://s2.postimg.org/eoyjdgepl/ipad.png).

I tried searching on stack and the web for people have had similar issues but to no avail. I hope somebody can clearly articulate the solution for others who may have the same issue. Thank-you.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will solve your problem (don't have an iDevice to try), but your `label` should have a `for` attribute:

```
 <label for="condo">Condo</label>
```

That way the label behaves like a part of the relevant `input`, for example, clicking the label has the same effect as clicking the input (toggling a checkbox, or focusing on the text for textboxes...)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out addition of the `for` attribute, however it did impact the margin/spacing between the label and check box.

Comment: It did, or it didn't? (If it did then that's what you wanted, no?)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity Amit. Your suggestion did not solve the problem.